# Multiple threads using the same event handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, eventhandler

I have a class that publishes an event handler:

```
public class X
{
    public event EventHandler<T> someEvent;
}
```

On the constructor, I span several threads. On all those threads I execute this event if some condition arise:

```
someEvent?.Invoke(this, new T()); //T will eventually contain some output data
```

Is it correct to assume that if several threads call the event at the same time, it should be no problem as long as the attached event handler knows how to deal with the multithreading issue? For example, if the attached event uses some locking mechanism or some concurrent collection to handle the output data? Or should this be handled in some other way?

As a follow up question: Should I lock the access to the event from the class:

```
lock(lockingObj)
{
    someEvent?.Invoke(this, new T()); //T will eventually contain some output data
}
```

or is that not neccesary if the attached event handles the situation properly? (I'm guessing that if three threads fire the event at the same time, the attached code is running three times as well on different threads).

Comment: You'll need to add some more information. When does `someEvent` get set for example? On a separate note, doing work in a constructor is usually a bad idea.

Comment: The work is done on the threads, never on the constructor. The constructor...construcsts the threads. That's what the constructor is for.

Comment: `Is it correct to assume that if several threads call the event at the same time, it should be no problem as long as the attached event handler knows how to deal with the multithreading issue` Yup, it is correct. Events are thread-safe at least since .net 2.0 (not so sure about 1.1, but who cares anymore)

Comment: Fair enough on the work not being done in the constructor. If the threads are locking on a common sync root, it seems like it should be fine as Kevin mentioned. My concern was about when `someEvent` was assigned.